# listview with navigator push to different screens not a single screen

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I have `listview` and this is the expected behaviour:

- When I click on 1st listview item, I want it to navigate me to screen "A",
- When I click on 2nd listview item, I want it to navigate me to screen "C",
- When I click on 3rd listview item, I want it to navigate me to screen "T",
- And so on...

In short, when I click on each listview item, I want it to navigate to a different screen, as I have different screens and differnt data.

IMPORTANT:
"navigating to a single screen" is everywhere, but I didn't get help on how to navigate to different screens. On youtube and google articles everyone has uploaded the same way, as they have same type of data in a single screen. The difference in my case is that I have multiple screens and every screen has its own unique data.

CODE:

```
class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  final CategoriesScroller categoriesScroller = CategoriesScroller();
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  bool closeTopContainer = false;
  double topContainer = 0;

  List<Widget> itemsData = [];

  void getPostsData() {
    List<dynamic> responseList = FOOD_DATA;
    List<Widget> listItems = [];
    responseList.forEach((post) {
      listItems.add(GestureDetector(
         onTap: () {
          _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
        },
        child: Container(

          height: 150,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)), color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Colors.black.withAlpha(100), blurRadius: 10.0),
          ]),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
            child: Row(

              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      post["name"],
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/${post["image"]}",
                  height: double.infinity,
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),));
    });
    setState(() {
      itemsData = listItems;
    });
  }
```

[image: This is how my screen look like]

Comment: share your code please

Comment: edited my question ...uploaded code

Comment: here is a picture ...https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRTl1.png

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

You will pass both `context and item index`

```
_navigateAndDisplaySelection(context, 1) // consider index 1
```

In `_navigateAndDisplaySelection(context)`, you will change it as like as code follow:

```
_navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context, int index){
// here you check the index and then route the navigation 

if(index==1){
//navigate add customer
}

if(index==2){
//navigate search customer
}

}
```

Comment: void _navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
  // Navigator.push returns a Future that completes after calling
  // Navigator.pop on the Selection Screen.
  if(index==1){
//navigate add customer
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchCustomerScreen()),
    );
  }

Comment: error: Undefined name 'index'. (undefined_identifier at [flutter_auth] lib\Screens\Dashboard\DashboardScreen.dart:147)

Comment: you need to assign index  ` in `_navigateAndDisplaySelection` can you share _navigateAndDisplaySelection code

Comment: edited my answer, please try to understand the concept and then go for code